# Elements break on Window Resize

Tags: html, css

Please consider that I am a ***newbie*** in CSS!

I am trying to build a simple webpage having some CSS properties, but the problem is that my webpage is alright in fully maximized window **but the design breaks down when I try to re-size the browser window**.

*Webpage source :*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration From</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-color:#d2d2ff;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            width:100%;
        }

        header
        {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            height:90px;
            background-color:#a0b7e0;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 90px #00000f;
        }

        footer
        {
            margin-top:40%;
            height:40px;
            background-color:#a0b7e0;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #00000f;
            position:relative;
        }

        .text_h
        {
            text-align:center;
            color:white;
            font-size:65px;
            text-shadow:2px 2px 1px #555555;
        }

        .text_f
        {
            text-align:center;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-size:15px;
            text-shadow:2px 2px 1px #555555;
            padding-top:0.7%;
        }

        cont1
        {   
            height:43%;
            width:12%;
            border:1px solid black;
            background-color:#c9c9c9;
            float:left;
            margin-top:2%;
            margin-left:1%;
            border-radius:7px; 
            box-shadow:0px 2px 15px #00000f;        
        }

        cont2
        {
            height:73%;
            width:84%;
            border:1px solid black;
            background-color:#e2e2e2;
            float:left;
            margin-top:2%;
            margin-left:2%;
            border-radius:7px; 
            box-shadow:0px 2px 15px #00000f;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .ql
        {
            text-align:left;
            color:#829fd7;
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
            padding-left:4%;
        }

        .list
        {
            color:#1f1f1f;
            font-size:18px;
            text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #555555;
            list-style-type: circle;
        }

        a
        {
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        a:hover
        {
            color:white;
            font-weight:bold;
            padding-left:4%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="text_h">Basic Homepage</div>
    </header>
    <cont1>
        <p class="ql">Quick Links</p>
            <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="#home">Homepage</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#abut">About Us</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#msg">Message</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#reg">Registration</a></li>
            </ul>
    </cont1>
    <cont2></cont2>
    <footer>
        <div class="text_f">&copy; 2014 Neeraj Singh</div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Can anyone please suggest me the right way to do it?**

Comment: It'll be better if you add the full html & css. Otherwise it'll be hard to understand, you can also provide a jsFiddle link.

Comment: I have provided the ful source code in my question!

Comment: You need to define the doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) as well as meta for viewport (if you want to support media queries). Also, if you are testing in IE it will default to quirks mode without `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see a couple issues with your code that I would definitely go ahead and fix:

1) `<cont1>` and `<cont2>` are not valid HTML tags. If you want to differentiate between two of the same tags, use [classes or ids](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

2) The top of your document is missing some key items which make a page render correctly. Replace `<html>` with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and add the following [meta tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-META) before your `<title>` tag:
    `<meta charset='utf-8' />`
    `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">`
    `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">`
    `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`

As for your question, it depends on your definition of when a design 'breaks down.' If you're talking about the word wrap of the header, you can apply a `mid-width` to your css, which will force the page to be scrollable when the screen becomes too small. To avoid future issues with this, you could put the `min-width` on the `html` and `body` elements of the page. Like:`html, body { min-width:800px;}`. Hope that helps to get you started!

Comment: I threw together a quick fiddle with some of the changes I spoke about (everything but the meta tags, which you'll have to put in yourself).. http://jsfiddle.net/V973u/

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is use CSS Media Queries to apply styling at specific screen size breakpoints.  The should look like this:

@media screen and (min-width:###px ) and (max-width: ###px ) {

/* enter styles that appliy here */

}

Use these for diferent screen sizes.  I use one for mobile phones and one for tablets.  These can go either at the top or bottom of your stylesheet.  But for readability keep the together.

Comment: You can also use @media to define specific styles for device type and Print styles.  It is a very powerful tool.

Comment: I think your answer is related to display problems on other devices, I am talking of browser window resize problem!

Comment: media queries using screen size checks for number of pixles in browser window. If you re-size your browser window you reduce the width, thus causing the number of pixles to drop. This is one of the big parts of building a responsive web site. Give it a shot using some thing easy like  body { background-color: red;} inside of a media query with max width of 768px then resize the browser window.  Once you drop down to less than 768px the screen will go red.

Comment: Can you post my code with your corrections if possible?

Comment: I can do so, when I get home tonight, but it will be a few hours.